# Error prepare() on a non-object with mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting a PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Config/functions.php on line 30.

Functions.php

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {


if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * 
    FROM users
   WHERE email = ?
    LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email); 
    $stmt->execute();   
    $stmt->store_result();
```

The $mysqli is getting it's data from a constants in another file which has been included

```
if (login($email, $password, $mysqli)     == true) {
    // Login success 
    header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
} else {
    // Login failed 
    header('Location: ../login.php?error=1');
}
```

Comment: and where is the initialization of $mysqli!

Comment: If `$mysqli` is just a variable in a file not class variable you can declear in inside the function like `global $mysqli;` in first line of your function

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
// Contents of constants.php
define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "root");
define("PASS", "pass");
define("DATABASE", "test");
// End of constants.php

include('constants.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);

function login($email, $password) 
{
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) 
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh no, even he didn't mean such a terrible implementation which connects to a database for the every function call

Comment: Copy paste mistake, ofcourse the connection call must not be inside the function

Comment: `*sigh*` and now you made it worse than in the question

Comment: That doesn't work. Still getting the same error in my apache logs